# stop solution build on first compilation\link error - msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, msbuild

I'm compiling a solution with many projects inside using VS2013's MSBuild. I want the build to stop if one of the projects fails to compile and that the error code of msbuild will be non-zero to indicate something has failed. Can it be done?

I am running this command to start compiling:

%MS_BUILD_PATH% "%workarea%\WindowsSolution.sln" /p:Configuration=Release /p:ContinueOnError=false /p:StopOnFirstFailure=true

but it doesn't work as I want it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14):

If anyone is still looking for this feature in Visual Studio, there is a free extension called `[VSColorOutput]` ([here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MikeWard-AnnArbor.VSColorOutput)), which has an option to stop the build on first build error. Once you have installed the extension, the options is located at: `Tools.Options.VSColorOutput.Build Actions.Stop Build On First Error`

Answer (score 3):

The [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) says `StopOnFirstFailure: If true, when one of the projects fails to build, no more projects will be built. Currently this is not supported when building in parallel (with multiple processors).`

Can you try setting `BuildInParallel=false` and see if that helps?

Edit: Found an old blog post that says this might be easy to do if you're building a single .sln with multiple projects http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manishagarwal/archive/2006/05/09/593392.aspx

Comment: FYI, dead link for that blog

Answer (score 3):

I'm using StopOnFirstBuildError

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EinarEgilsson.StopOnFirstBuildError

It stops the build when the any project building fails.  I'm using on 2015.  The linked page says it works with Visual Studio 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017.