# When building in Visual Studio 2020, stop on the first build error without installing any extensions

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-2019

Similar to [stop solution build on first compilation\link error - msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449330/stop-solution-build-on-first-compilation-link-error-msbuild) and [VS2010 - How to automatically stop compile on first compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041982/vs2010-how-to-automatically-stop-compile-on-first-compile-error), but I don't want to install any VS extensions that aren't from official sources (i.e. Microsoft), and I want my build to stop on the first error. Is that possible?

Comment: This used to be possible in pre-2012 versions using a [macro](https://www.danrigby.com/2009/10/04/automatically-cancelling-a-failed-build-in-visual-studio/), but then VS retired macros. There is an MS-provided [macros extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio) though I haven't tried it. Another possibility might be using (ms)build events, but that's at the project level and language dependent.